# Spring Boot jdbc session with/without servlet

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application to which I now want to add jdbc sessions.

The Spring documentation makes use of a [SessionServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-jdbc.html#how-does-it-work). Is this contrary to the @SpringBootApplication way of doing things or do I need a SessionServlet in addition to a SpringBootApplication class?

Comment: Can you explain what's *SpringBootApplication way of doing things*?

Comment: with a SpringBootApplication you don't need a Servlet class to listen to http requests, that is handled by the class with the SpringBootApplication annotation. If I add a SessionServlet, will that servlet listen to the http requests and as such conflict with the SpringBootApplication class?

Comment: do you want to manage your sessions in Db instead of locally?

Comment: @slimane yip I want to manage my sessions in a Db.

Comment: @dataphile have a look at spring session JDBC project, it's easy to integrate. but keep in mind that managing sessions using JDBC will decrease your env performance. I suggest to use a caching mechanism something like Redis it's also supported by spring